# Change variable value in TCL file and re-run simulation using bash script

Tags: bash, tcl

I have TCL file a.tcl from ns2 as follows :

```
set opt(x)              1000                                
set opt(y)              1000                                
set opt(z)              15                                  
set opt(per_11ac)       1                                   
set opt(nch)            4                                   
set opt(cbr_rate_DL)        0.05Mb                              
set opt(cbr_rate_UL)        10Mb
```

I want to change opt(cbr_rate_DL) value automatically from bash script hence for the next simulation I can change to 0.1Mb, 0.5Mb, and 10Mb and re-run the simulation with new value. How to do that in bash script?

Comment: Is the question here how to automate changing a specific value in a file? Because if it is then personally I would say "Don't do that". Instead change the script to read that value from a command line argument or environment variable or something like that instead.

Comment: Agreed with Etan. Still you need, then it is not about a `tcl` file. You need to know, how to read/write/manipulate a normal file using Shell script. Tcl has nothing to do with it as per your need if you need a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop construct to do this

```
for val in 0.1 0.5 10
do
   sed -i "/set opt(cbr_rate_DL)/ s/[0-9.]\+/$val/" a.tcl
   // run the simulation here
done
```

the sed script above modifies the a.tcl file inplace (`-i`) .
It first search each line for `/set opt(cbr_rate_DL)/`. if line contains set opt(cbr_rate_DL)  if so substitutes for number sequence with dots `s/[0-9.]\+/$val/` with the value in `$val`

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is probably to pass the value in using an environment variable. In Tcl scripts, environment variables are mapped to the global `env` array, so you change your code to include use (with extra spaces and commentary for clarity):

```
# Set up a default, for safety
set opt(cbr_rate_DL)        0.05Mb

# Has the environment variable been set?
if {[info exists env(CBR_RATE_DL)]} {

    # It has! Copy to where it belongs
    set opt(cbr_rate_DL)    $env(CBR_RATE_DL)
}
```

Then you can run your script with another value there by just setting the `CBR_RATE_DL` environment variable to whatever you want. (Remember to `export` it from your shell if you're using a bourne-shell-derived environment, of course.)